# Require.js  что такое модуль?

Tags: javascript

Привет .
Читая статью [link](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/10/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-requirejs/) у меня возник вопрос что такое модуль?
В моем понимании при разработке в модуль входят набор файлов которые выполняют одним общий функционал.
Может модуль в понимании require.js это задание имени при использовании которого будут включены все файлы для создания этого модуля?
Далеее делал пример тестовый

```
require.config({

    //baseUrl: "/another/path",
    paths: {
        'first': '1',
        'second': '2', 
        'root': '3',
        'fouth':4,
        'fifth':5
    },

  shim : {
  'second' : {deps : ['first']},
  'root'  :{ deps : ['second'] },
  'fifth':{deps:['fouth']},
  'fouth':{deps:['first']}
}

});

define( 'my',['fouth','fifth'], function(){

  console.log('Inintialize json');
  console.log(json);
  console.log(obj);
}),

define( 'other',['root'], function(){

console.log('upload')
})

require('my');
```

Получаю ошибку :
**Error: Module name "my" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded**

Comment: require(['my']); - не?..